# Infinispan 9.1: Unsupported async cache mode 'REPL_ASYNC' for transactional caches

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, infinispan-9

I'm migrating the project to Infinispan 9.1.0.Final from 8.2.4.Final and got next exception:

> org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: ISPN000441: Unsupported async cache mode 'REPL_ASYNC' for transactional caches

Related code:

```
new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .jmxStatistics()
            .enabled(false)
            .available(false)
            .clustering()
            .cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_ASYNC)
            .stateTransfer().awaitInitialTransfer(false)
            .transaction()
            .transactionManagerLookup(new DummyTransactionManagerLookup())
            .transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
            .lockingMode(LockingMode.PESSIMISTIC)
            .recovery()
            .enabled(false)
            .invocationBatching()
            .enable(false)
            .indexing()
            .index(Index.ALL)
            .addProperty("default.indexmanager", "near-real-time")
            .addProperty("default.directory_provider", "ram")
            .addProperty("default.worker.execution", "sync")
            .addProperty("default.exclusive_index_use", "true")
            .addProperty("default.reader.strategy", "shared")
            .build();
```

And problem combination here, but in 8.2.4.Final version this works well.

```
.cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_ASYNC)
.transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL) // Maybe is there another way to lock put operations?
```

How should I reconfig cache to save its characteristics?

Answer (score 2):

The async mode for transactional caches wasn't safe since it didn't wait for the transaction to commit in every node in the cluster before reporting to the `TransactionManager`. It can make your data inconsistent if you are unlucky.

To avoid any issues, it was removed. Please upgrade your configuration to use `REPL_SYNC` instead.

Also, the `DummyTransactionManagerLookup` was deprecated and it should be replaced by `EmbeddedTransactionManagerLookup`.

There are other transaction related change between 8.x and 9.x. Please take a look at the upgrade guide (http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/upgrading/upgrading.html#upgrading_from_8_x_to_9_0) for more details.

Comment: It is working solution, but the application very often puts elements to part of the distributed cache, and now, with REPL_ASYNC, updated node informs other ones about this event. And they update own cache instances automatically. With REPL_SYNC requested node must ask other to give fresh element, therefore put's latency will be suffitiently increased. What can you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your use case, but do you really transaction? Non-transactional caches can still use the async mode.

If you don't need the previous value from the put(k,v), you can set the IGNORE_RETURN_VALUES like:
 AdvanceCache.withFlags(IGNORE_RETURN_VALUES).put(k,v),
but it sill needs to go remote to acquire the lock (if the node isn't the lock owner).